# How Can I Mirror & Control Android Device on Large Mulit-touch Screen

Tags: remote-control

I want to build a gaming table for my children. Ideally, I would simply connect an Android device (such as a tablet/mobile phone) through USB/HDMI to a multitouch monitor. Is this possible?

The closest example I've seen is this one (from 2011). I'm assuming there have been further developments in this area since this article was published.

http://liliputing.com/2011/09/two-way-sync-between-an-android-tablet-and-a-touchscreen-monitor.html

If anyone could give me a lug & play solution, that would be ideal, but I'm not against hacking something together (or example, if something like the Raspberry PI is required) with easy to understand instructions. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure enough of anything to make an answer, but I would like to direct you to this [XDA Discussion on the topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1294268). It seems several external touchscreens are indeed compatible. Have you already picked a commercial touchscreen device that you'll be using? Or will you be building your screen and finger tracker yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is now possible and recently I saw a demo unit that meets your requirement. 
The demo was from HANNspree and they connected their 23" touch monitor (HT231HPB) together with their 10" Tablet. 
You can also use the touch-screen monitor to control the action on the Android device.
In few words a two-way sync between the tablet and the touch monitor.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! The question was ***HOW*** it can be done, not ***IF*** it can be done. Could you please [edit] your answer and include this part? Thanks in advance!